# Confused to understand program output

Tags: java, oop, object

Here is a program

```
public class MovieTitle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Movie one = new Movie();
        one.title = "I am title";
        one.playIt();
        System.out.println(one.title);
    }
}

class Movie {
    String title;
    void playIt() {
        this.title = "I am title of movie";
    }
}
```

The output is **"I am title of movie"** 
I am trying to understand it but till now I do not understand it properly.
I want to know: **Why does it not print "I am title"**

Comment: I hope this is not example code at school.

Comment: what happened to the code snippet?

Comment: Why the down votes? OP has written some code and is requesting an explanation, sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: That's the way how our beautiful community works...

Comment: If you want to understand what a program is doing and why, the best tool to use is the debugger.  It is usually next Run in you IDE. Add a break point at the start of the program and step through it and you will see exactly what each line does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sequence of events:

```
// create a new Movie called "one"
Movie one = new Movie();

// at this point, one.title is still null

// set the title to "I am title"
one.title = "I am title";

// call playIt, which in turn ...
one.playIt();
   // sets the title to something else again
   => this.title = "I am title of movie";
```

If you printed the title before calling `playIt`, it would still show as "I am title".

Answer (score 1):

Does this illustrate why:

```
public class MovieTitle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Movie one = new Movie();
        System.out.println(one.title);
        one.title = "I am title";
        System.out.println(one.title);
        one.playIt();
        System.out.println(one.title);
    }
}

class Movie {
    String title;
    void playIt() {
        this.title = "I am title of movie";
    }
}
```

Here's the corresponding output:

```
java MovieTitle
null
I am title
I am title of movie
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause you set when you call playIt() the title to "I am title of movie";
Try changing the order of the two lines

```
one.title = "I am title";
one.playIt();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you trace out the calls, it should become fairly obvious.

```
Movie one = new Movie();
```

title will be NULL at this point (ie, it has had no value assigned)

```
one.title = "I am title";
```

Now your Movie object one has the title "I am title"

```
one.playIt();
```

Calls the playIt() method on one, which sets the title of "this" (which is one) to "I am title of movie"

Answer (score 0):

You asign `"I am title"` to the `title` varible in object `one` of type `Movie`.

When you call method `playIt()` in the same object, varible title gets asigned another value `"I am title of movie"`.

If you invert the lines like so

```
one.playIt(); 
one.title = "I am title";
```

The output is going to be `"I am title"`, because you set this value, after you call `playIt()` method.